# How do I show the time of a process in minix, using the library time.h?

Tags: c, process, output, minix, time.h

time_t t;

printf("%f\n",time(&t));

it throws "Can not print float number"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Get Current Date

time_t data type depends on your platform. 
To solve this issue, you can try to cast it to `long long`. And directly print it:

```
printf("%lld\n", (long long) time(NULL));
```

## Measure time taken by a function or process

If you want to calculate the time of a process or a function create a clock_t variable and calculate the difference:

```
clock_t t; 
t = clock(); 
myfunction(); 
t = clock() - t;
```

Note that `t` is the measured time value here.

Answer (score 1):

You may try

`#include <stdlib.h>
printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t) time(NULL));`.